# Правильно ли я использую SearchView в качестве EditText?

Tags: java, android, xml

Здравствуйте, я столкнулся с проблемой при использовании `SearchView` в качестве `EditText`. Не знаю как решить её. SearchView является элементом меню:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@android:string/search_go"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

В методе `OnCreate` я делаю следующее:

```
EditText userFilter;
userFilter = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.action_search);
```

И получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

Не судите строго, я еще новичок и плохо разбираюсь в разработке под android.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tool_menu, menu);
    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Меню в момент вызова OnCreate ещё не создано. Вам надо обращаться к нему в методе `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`

Также вы не сможете найти его в разметке актвити. Вам надо будет найти содержащий поле ввода элемент меню по его ID из аргумента помянутого выше метода, получить его `actionView` и уже в нём попробовать поискать по ID. Либо пользовать сам `SearchView` кои и будет результатом вызова `MenuItem#getActionView()`

Answer (score 0):

В общем, нашёл решение:

```
TextView searchText = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
```